# Live search на javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Нашел такой код на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/rFGWZ/):

```js
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val();

  $("table tr").each(function(index) {
    if (index !== 0) {

      $row = $(this);

      var id = $row.find("td:first").text();

      if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
        $row.hide();
      } else {
        $row.show();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Unique ID</th>
    <th>Random ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>214215</td>
    <td>442</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1252512</td>
    <td>556</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2114</td>
    <td>4666</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3245466</td>
    <td>334</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>24111</td>
    <td>54364</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search"></input>`
```

Скрипт работает, все нормально, но как сделать чтоб по началу данные таблицы не отображались а начали отображаться после того как пользователь начинает набирать текст?

Comment: можно попробовать через css задать display: none таблице, а после запуска функции, в функцию добавить другую функцию, которая будет изменять css-свойство на display: block

Comment: А без CSS никак не обойтись ? Просто очень слабо разбираюсь в CSS

Comment: можно через js задать свойства, а что там разбираться в css?) я уже подсказал что прописывать нужно :)

Comment: Спасибо а как это будет выглядит ?

Comment: Спасибо всё понял !)

Comment: @AlexStassov если вы всё поняли после моего ответа, то можете его ответить принятым :)

Comment: Да конечно но я почему то не вижу такую кнопку ( где она находиться

Comment: @AlexStassov рядом с ответом :-) http://prntscr.com/fbwxbw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С самого начала можно скрывать все `<tr>`, которые находятся в `<tbody>`, а заголовочные ячейки объединить в `<thead>`.

```js
$("#table-for-search tbody tr").hide();

$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val();

  $("table tr").each(function(index) {
    if (index !== 0) {

      $row = $(this);

      var id = $row.find("td:first").text();

      if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
        $row.hide();
      } else {
        $row.show();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id=table-for-search>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Unique ID</th>
      <th>Random ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>214215</td>
    <td>442</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1252512</td>
    <td>556</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2114</td>
    <td>4666</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3245466</td>
    <td>334</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>24111</td>
    <td>54364</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search">
```

Comment: В таком случае скрываются все таблицы на странице )

Comment: Ну так сделайте селектор, который будет скрывать только конкретную.

Comment: Так-то и ваш код счас ищет по всем таблицам и скрывает/показывает данные во всех таблицах.

Comment: вот именно что не скрывает и не ищет по всем таблицам как ни странно )

Comment: Именно что ищет по всем таблицам. Можете проверить — скопировать-вставить прямо в моем коде несколько раз эту таблицу и поискать нужные данные.

Comment: Сделал вам поиск по конкретной таблице, не забудьте добавить айди.

Comment: Спасибо Вам Sasha Omelchenko вы мне очень помогли , поставил ID table-for-search но теперь почему то изначально тоже таблица отображается в чем может быть причина ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59284/discussion-between-sasha-omelchenko-and-alex-stassov).